# Should a moderator merge the questions about the pronunciation of the name "Sean"?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, exact-duplicates, merged-questions

- [Why do we pronounce Dean as /diːn/ but Sean as /ʃɒn/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68758/why-do-we-pronounce-dean-as-di%CB%90n-but-sean-as-%CA%83%C9%92n)
- [Why is Sean pronounced Shawn?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217012/why-is-sean-pronounced-shawn)

I think I was the first one to vote for closing the first as a duplicate of the second, and now I feel stupid for not noticing the relative dates. Anyway, it seems to me that all of the existing answers on each question are equally suitable for both, so would a merge be appropriate here? I'm a bit hazy on the process for that; since a moderator has to do it, it seems like merges are a lot rarer than closing as duplicates.

I've read these meta posts

- [What are merged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-are-merged-questions)
- [Are there guidelines on direction for merging questions (which question to close/merge?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107846/are-there-guidelines-on-direction-for-merging-questions-which-question-to-close?rq=1)

But I'm interested in learning about what people think about this specific case, and what the moderators here have to say about the merging process on this site. (This is why I didn't just flag it.)

Comment: I guess I should have just flagged it.